# Converting tif to format for TIMESAT using BEAM VISAT or ERDAS IMAGINE?

Tags: convert, erdas-imagine, geotiff-tiff

How can I convert tif image into a format for TIMESAT software to create a time series?

I am using BEAM VISAT or ERDAS IMAGINE program.

Answer (score 2):

I looked on the TIMESAT homepage and quickly found:

> TIMESAT reads and writes raw, or flat, binary files, one file per
>   image. Currently 8-bit unsigned integer, 16-bit signed integer or
>   32-bit signed real data are supported. Many remote sensing software
>   packages store the data as flat binary files with auxiliary header
>   files. In most cases these binary files can be used directly with
>   TIMESAT without any conversion, given that they are in the correct
>   numeric format (e.g. Idrisi, PCI CIM2, EASI).

Click on [**File Formats**](http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/timesat.asp?cat=5) on the main page.  There you'll see that they recommend using [**GDAL**](http://www.gdal.org/index.html) to convert to flat binary format.

Here's **[an instruction page](http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/docs/Getting%20image%20data%20into%20TIMESAT.pdf)** on getting data in and out of TIMESAT.

ERDAS Imagine should almost certainly be able to export to the format you need.  You may need to convert your data type if it isn't in 8-bit unsigned int, 16-bit signed int, or 32-bit signed real.